# Set cursor at end of string in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I wrote the code below to set the first letter to upper case and set the data in CKEditor. The first letter is converting fine, but afterward, the cursor focus is set before the first letter. How can I set the cursor after the character?

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
    e.editor.on('contentDom', function () {
        e.editor.document.on('keyup', function (event) {
            var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
            var str = $(data).text();
            var n = str.length;
            if (str != null && n == 1) {
                CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(titleCase(str))
                function titleCase(string) {
                    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code is work for you :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {

        ev.editor.focus();

        var s = ev.editor.getSelection(); // getting selection
        var selected_ranges = s.getRanges(); // getting ranges
        var node = selected_ranges[0].startContainer; // selecting the starting node
        var parents = node.getParents(true);

        node = parents[parents.length - 2].getFirst();

        while (true) {
            var x = node.getNext();
            if (x == null) {
                break;
            }
            node = x;
        }

        s.selectElement(node);
        selected_ranges = s.getRanges();
        selected_ranges[0].collapse(false);  //  false collapses the range to the end of the selected node, true before the node.
        s.selectRanges(selected_ranges);  // putting the current selection there
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hello @Rajnik Patel. thanks for your replay,but the above one is not working, directly it goes to second line ,and the character also not Converting to upper case.

Comment: @RanjeethKumarVootukuri please check again this code work successfully from my side..

Comment: hi @Rajnik Patel, in my asp page in  $(document).ready(function() i put your code and my code(above One),but its not working for me.please could you modify your above code exactly what your are done?

Comment: please use `instanceReady` event insted of `instanceCreated`

Comment: Again Same it does same thing,goes to next line

Comment: With My above Code I am convert first letter  to upper case in Ckeditor,but the problem is after converting the cursor is at Leftside of letter,So here i want to come cursor at right side of letter,